# Ajax and MVC 5 - Upload image binary by ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am writing code using knockoutjs and mvc5 where an image is selected on the ui and the binary of the image is uploaded via ajax.

I cant really show much surrounding the image upload, but I know it works. The image is local to the browser and the binary is stored in the view model.

The problem is uploading this binary to mvc.

In my javascript, I am constructing a post using the following:

```
var customerData = {
    CustomerName: self.CustomerName(),
    CustomerImage: self.CustomerImage().imageBinary(),
    CustomerJobNumber: self.CustomerJobNumber()
};
//If add, enable remaining area, change id, and start customer edit
if (window.location.hash == "#customer-add") {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Customer/SaveNew",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(customerData),
        success: function(data) {
            /*CODE*/
            var title = data.title;
            var msg = data.message;
            if (data.success == 0) {
                //growl as to why
            } else {
                //growl success
                window.location.hash = "#customer-edit-" + data.newCustomer.CustomerId;
                self.SetCustomerFields(data.newCustomer);
                self.LoadCustomers();
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
            //growl
        }
    });
}
```

And in my controller I have:

```
    public class NewCustomerData
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public byte[] CustomerImage { get; set; }
        public string CustomerJobNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveNew(NewCustomerData data)
    {
          //Does stuff
    }
```

When I break into the javascript running, the CustomerImage object that I am sending is of type ArrayBuffer. If I convert it to an Uint8Array I can verify there are contents. But the binary never appears in the controller.

Am I not assigning the correct c# object?

Comment: Please also post your view

Comment: Is the view even necessary? The issue im having is posting the ArrayBuffer to the controller using ajax. I have the data right before the ajax call but it vanishes somewhere between the ajax call and being picked up by the controller method.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab on the browser to verify the correct data is being dent to the server? Normally I would use HttpPostedFileBase in the model rather than byte[]

Comment: I guess the issue is with the content-type. What does your JSON.stringify(customerData) show? I guess the correct way to do this would be to convert your CustomerImage object to an Uint8Array as you did, and then send to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this was to convert the ArrayBuffer in the JavaScript to a Base-64 encoded string. I then modified the object on the server side to accept a string and voila.

Comment: If you're using a FileReader, you can read it as a dataURL which encodes it to base64 with some other data, then use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710576/convert-from-a-dataurl-to-an-image-in-c-sharp-and-write-a-file-with-the-bytes) to decode it. It seems btoa has some peculiarities when converting data to base64.