# Convert from a DataUrl to an Image in C# and write a file with the bytes

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, memorystream, xamarin.forms

Hello I have signature like this:

[image]

which is encoded to a Data Url specifically this string:

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZAAAADICAYAAADGFbfiAAAYlElEQVR4Xu2dC8w1R1nHQSCIgIKVGLmoiLciFwUs... (long string)`

What i want to do is Convert this Data Url to an PNG Image, and save the image to the device, this is what i am doing so far:

```
if (newItem.FieldType == FormFieldType.Signature)
{
     if (newItem.ItemValue != null)
     {
           //string completeImageName = Auth.host + "/" + li[i];
           string path;
           string filename;
           string stringName = newItem.ItemValue;

           var base64Data = Regex.Match(stringName, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
           var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

           path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

           filename = Path.Combine(path, base64Data);

           if (!File.Exists(filename))
           {
                 using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binData))
                 {
//Code crashing here--------------------------
                      File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binData);
                  }
            }

        newItem.ItemValue = filename;

    }
}

         App.Database.SaveReportItem(newItem);
```

But my code is making my application to crash specifically in this line:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binData);
```

The sample I am using as reference ([Link](https://gist.github.com/vbfox/484643)) is using a PictureBox but with Xamarin there is no use of a pictureBox.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why are you creating a MemoryStream?

Comment: Is it crashing on iOS or Android?  And, ask SLaks asked, why open a stream and not use it?  Are you sure your filename is getting set to a valid value?

Comment: Looking at the output, (Using Android) this is the error let me change the path "Could not find a part of the path "/data/data/"

Comment: what are the values of path and filename?  It sounds like you are not building a valid path.

Comment: You are exactly right I am now using this: `filename = Path.Combine(path, base64Data.Replace(@"/", string.Empty));` but now my path its too long I am going to use the current time in miliseconds to create the file name.

Comment: Hi friend, how did you made that control in Xamarin.Forms? I just need to implemente a tactile signature and then send it to server as image in base64. Thanks, wainting for your response.

Comment: To implement the signature: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/176118#Comment_176118 but for sending the base64 image I haven't done that yet, hope this helps.

Comment: How did you make this work in C#?  WHen I try and use File.WriteAllBytes, it is looking for 3 string arguments....

Comment: @dave317 are you using a PCL or a Shared project? and File.WriteAllBytes is from System.IO: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes/p/System.String/System.Byte[]/

Comment: I'm actually not using xamarin at all.   I think thats my issue.  I'm using ASP.NET. I have a using System.IO; statement in my controller, but its not working.

Comment: @dave317 that may be the problem.

Comment: You should remove that regex matching as it is very slow. You could use something like this instead:
    `s.Substring(s.IndexOf(",")+1).Trim();`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @SLaks mentioned I didn't need a MemoryStream, the problem with my code was the path and the filename for further help this is the working code:

```
if (newItem.FieldType == FormFieldType.Signature)
{
    if (newItem.ItemValue != null)
    {
        //string completeImageName = Auth.host + "/" + li[i];
        string path;
        string filename;
        string stringName = newItem.ItemValue;

        var base64Data = Regex.Match(stringName, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
        var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

        path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        //filename = Path.Combine(path, base64Data.Replace(@"/", string.Empty));

        long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        string fileName = "Sn" + milliseconds.ToString() + ".PNG";
        filename = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            //using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binData))
            //{
                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binData);
            //}
        }

        newItem.ItemValue = filename;

    }
}

App.Database.SaveReportItem(newItem);
```

And the image showed:

[image]

Comment: No need for the regex. You only need to split at the comma to get the data from the data url. Official format is: `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

Answer (score 17):

I just cleaned Mario's code and fine tuned regex:

```
public string SaveDataUrlToFile(string dataUrl, string savePath)
{
    var matchGroups = Regex.Match(dataUrl, @"^data:((?<type>[\w\/]+))?;base64,(?<data>.+)$").Groups;
    var base64Data = matchGroups["data"].Value;
    var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, binData);
    return savePath;
}
```